Which is considered better practice for defining range() for a loop in python? Using len() or a defined variable?
Can't seem to find a answer for this. Which is considered better practice?
For example, let's say I have an array of length = 6. Let's also say that it is a sorting algorithm that changes in place and I need the indexes.
for i in range(len(array)):

or
for i in range(6):

?
Can anyone point me to the right media that could definitively answer this question?

The first needs no adjustment if array changes, that would make it better in my book.

...and of course, in most cases you only need for i in array; the answer to this question really depends on your specific situation.

Rather than having a loop over the indexes, loop over the actual elements of the array.  If you need the indexes too, you can use enumerate.

I added the condition that it is for a sorting algorithm that changes in place and need the indexes.

@OneCriketeer: are you sure this is opinion based? Are you sure there is not official documentation or research that can resolve this question? I was hoping someone in Stackoverflow could point me to the right media.

If you are iterating over an array, I would go with:
for i, item in enumerate(array):
   pass

This construct:

Gives you both the item to work with and its index
Avoids range() generator that adds nothing to the semantics of the code
IMO, is more readable than range(len(..

